# Calling a method vs setattr

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I need to call a method or change an attribute of the class, and I don't know exactly which it's going to be in advance. For now my code looks like this:

```
def change(obj, attr_name, val):
    attr = getattr(obj, attr_name, None)
    # check if attr exists
    if type(attr) == 'NoneType':
        print('no such attribute')
        return
   
    if callable(attr):
        attr(val)
    else:
        setattr(obj, attr_name, val)
```

However, it doesn't seem very elegant to me.
I've tried googling this for a couple of days and can't find an answer.

I was using this to call methods of an object which names I didn't know in advance. As I understand from reading python literature it is valid to use getattr in this case. However, later I started to decorate some of my methods with `@property` and when I try to call them with `getattr(obj, attr_name)(value)` I get an error. Here's the code snippet to illustrate my problem:

```
class myclass1:
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = 'hello'
    def getA(self):
        return self._a
    def setA(self, val):
        self._a = val

class myclass2:
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = 'hello'
    @property
    def A(self):
        return self._a
    @A.setter
    def A(self, val):
        self._a = val

def changeOLD(obj, attr_name, val):
    attr = getattr(obj, attr_name, None)(val)

obj1 = myclass1()
obj2 = myclass2()
changeOLD(obj1, 'setA', 'goodbye')
print(obj1.getA())

changeOLD(obj2, 'A', 'goodbye')
print(obj2.A)
```

When I run it:

```
$ python test.py
goodbye
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 45, in <module>
    changeOLD(obj2, 'A', 'goodbye')
  File "test.py", line 37, in changeOLD
    attr = getattr(obj, attr_name, None)(val)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

So I figured I need a way to differentiate between attribute and method.

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve by this?

Comment: What's the use case for this function? I suspect it's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: In any case, `if type(x) == 'NoneType'` doesn't work, just use `if x is None`. And instead of checking if an attribute exists and if not print an error, just omit the default value for `getattr` and handle the resulting `AttributeError`.

Comment: How can it be that you don't know in advance?

Comment: I've updated my post

Comment: Can you show an example of a method you have decorated with `@property` and how you are trying to use it such that it gives you `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I've updated my post with full code snippet

Comment: `changeOLD` doesn't make sense to use with `myclass2`. You want `obj2.A = 'goodbye'` or `setattr(obj2, 'A', 'goodbye')`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no major problems with the code you've provided for the use case you've described. There are some changes you could do though.

I'd change so you check against `None` instead of the type of `None`. And printing is usually not done in a method that handles logic. You'd might also want to return the value from the function you're calling. Lastly, change the method name to something more fitting.

```
def set_or_call(obj, name, value):
    attr_or_function = getattr(obj, name, None)
    
    if attr_or_function is None:
        return None  # Or raise an exception if this is suppose to be an error.
    elif callable(attr_or_function):
        return attr_or_function(value)
    else:
        setattr(obj, attr_or_function, value)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated my original post